# How to escape backslash double quote in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string of data with each double quote escaped

```
\"\"data\"\": [ { \"\"type\"\": etc.
```

how can I remove the backslashes to convert the string to

```
""data"": [ { ""type"":
```

using C#, regex, or other method

I have tried `text.Replace(@"\"","")` but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure the quotes are actually escaped? The debugger displays strings with escapes. If you print them to the console, are the slashes still there?

Comment: Have you check the return value of the text.Replace ?

Comment: OP: when I check the debugger, any doubled double quotes are escaped with a backslash

Comment: Answer from Blorgbeard is correct!   Writing to Console, I realize that the debugging window was doing this, but the actual escapes were not there, thanks!

Comment: If you want to parse JSON, you should much rather install a NuGet package for that (Newtonsoft.Json) instead of writing a parser yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If one actually prints out the string such as:

```
var str = "\"\"data\"\": [ { \"\"type\"\": etc.";
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

One will see that the `\` is an C# precompile informational character that is not passed on to runtime.

The actual text in the memory buffer and when printed out is:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try code below

```
text.ToString().Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: This would be excellent at removing all double quotes in a string, but not the backslashes.